# Qt Jambi application and different operating systems

Tags: java, qt, qt-jambi

I'm starting to develop my new study project. Because I want and need to run it on different platforms (Linux and Windows) I decide to use Java. Also, because I want to learn something new - I have decided to use Qt Jambi. And here are my problems and doubts. I think that most of it are because I do not understand everything clearly... ;) For now, I develop my application mostly in .Net, and few in Java Swing.

Firstly, I'm using Windows 7 64bit and I want to develop most time on this system. So I've installed the new Eclipse Helios 64bit and Jave SE 64bit. And here is the first concern and problem:
1. It can be stupid, but if I'm using such a configuration, my application will be 32bit or 64bit? :)) It must be 32bit, 64bit can be an option...
2. I've download the Qt Jambi 4.6.3 from this site: http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtjambi/files/ and I can't run it... I've got such error:

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.trolltech.qt.QtJambiObject.<clinit>(QtJambiObject.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Loading library failed, progress so far:
Unpacking .jar file: 'qtjambi-win32-msvc2005-4.6.3.jar'
Checking Archive 'qtjambi-win32-msvc2005-4.6.3.jar'
 - skipping because of wrong system: trying to load: 'win32', expected: 'win64'
```

From this description I thought that the 64bit java and 32bit Qt is a problem. Because there is no Qt Jambi 4.6.3 for 64bit windows I've installed the 32 bit Java SE and Eclipse simultaneusly. But this do not help.
On the other hand, I found 64bit Qt Jambi from Nokia site - the last version with their support and everything works (only Qt Jambi.exe file not run, because could not find the jvm.dll, which is also strange....

What I want is to develop 32bit application in Java with newest stable Qt Jambi (4.6.3) which will run on Linux and Windows (both 32 and 64bit), and I'm developing in on 64bit Windows. My other questions are:
1. From documentation I understand that I need qtjambi.jar and the second one specific for each system because of C++. Is there any way to include all and make application to choose the right one during start up or intallation?
2. And for people developing in Qt - is better to use Eclipse plugin or to use Qt Creator and then juic ?
3. Some recommended books / tutorials will appreciate.

Thank you for patience to read that and for any answers :)
Michał

Comment: If you want to use the Qt jambi plugin for Eclipse, you have to use Qt Jambi 4.5, because Nokia didn't release the code for the plugin, so no plugin for 4.6 exists.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I do not write about the eclipse plugin problem - I just cannot compile any Qt Jambi 4.6.3 code in the environment I specified above...

Comment: See also my replies in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554754/qt-jambi-eclipse-integration-error-on-windows-64-bits/7570128#7570128
Your problem here is the same/very-similar as that other stackoverflow issue.  Infiel's JVM that is trying to load Qt Jambi is the 64bit JVM but the Qt Jambi DLLs are 32bit.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  To get it to work I have to remove the 64-bit java installations of Java 6 Update 22 and Java SE Developement Kit 6 update 22.  Once I removed these Eclipse helios new that it should use the 32 bit java stuff.

Comment: OR ... install BOTH versions of Java from Sun/Oracle website (both versions as in 64bit and 32bit).  Then follow the instructions I provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554754/qt-jambi-eclipse-integration-error-on-windows-64-bits/7570128#7570128 to allow the 32bit version of Eclipse to run on a 64bit Windows system.